# Any other way to get the browser info other than retrieving UserAgent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My scenario is to retrieve the browser and layout info - including the versions and keep them for history tracking. So this is not for checking functionality. Since JQuery.browser has been obsolete, I have seen the most popular way to walk around this is by reading navigator.userAgent. However, this value is unstable and can be overriden by browsers, I guess this should not be the recommended way. Is there any other way in doing this?

Comment: as far as I know, that's the only way...unless you want to do some testing on which HTML tags it supports to tell the IE version

Answer (score 4):

You really only have two choices:

1. You can believe the userAgent string
2. You can run all sorts of functionality tests on the browser to try to figure out which browser family and version it really is.

If you want to know a wide range of different browsers (including mobile browsers) and various versions of each, then identifying tests for each browser/version combination is a lot of work.

I'd say it really depends upon what you're collecting the info for.  If you're really just curious what browsers are using your app so you can perhaps direct your browser and testing support to those browsers that most use your app, then just using the user agent string is probably just fine for that.  The large majority of browsers will not be faking the useragent so if this is for statistical use, then a small numnber of fakes won't distort your numbers in any great way and using the useragent string is way, way simpler.

If, you're trying to decide, in a given browser, what javascript capability to rely on in that particular browser, then you're far, far better off devising a feature test to see if that browser actually has the capability you want to use because the consequences here of a false user agent string (or a wrong piece of useragent logic in your own code) is that the app just doesn't work properly in that browser.

---

One "middle" solution might be to identify only what family the browser is in (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc...) and you aren't concerned about exactly which version, then a set of features tests can probably discern that without too much trouble since every family tends to have at least a few identifying special features.  This would certainly be more work than just using the useragent, but a lot less work than trying to pin down the exact version using a feature test.

Another "middle" solution might be to identify the browser family via the above simpler feature test and then see if that agrees with the userAgent string and, if so, then you decide to believe the userAgent string for the version.  If not, you throw out the data figuring that the browser is lying to you somewhere (or your test has a slight flaw).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I asked this question because I read from Salesforce document that this value is optional and should not be relied on. But since now it is only option and it is working for most major browsers I guess it is good enough. I have sent Salesforce a document change request for this.